# Connect via bluetooth to an android device without a custom application

Tags: android-bluetooth

I would like to use an arduino with a bluetooth module to modify the volume and skip songs on my phone.

All the information I found was about how to code an application that would communicate with a device via bluetooth, which isn't what I am looking for. I want to know what *protocol* I should follow to connect to an android device via bluetooth like a car radio would do.

My goal is to be able to use my device as a remote to control the built-in music application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [AVRCP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Audio.2FVideo_Remote_Control_Profile_.28AVRCP.29). Please send more info about your hardware so I can digg a better answer (if you need more, anyways...).